# mplfinanceをインストールしようとするとエラーが出ます。

Tags: matplotlib

次のいずれかを試してもエラーが出ます。

```bash
pip install mplfinance
```

```bash
pip3 install mplfainace
```

すごい長いのですが、エラーは下の通りとなります。どのように対処すべきか、ご教示いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
C:\Users\masanori\Downloads>pip3 install mplfinance
Collecting mplfinance
  Using cached mplfinance-0.12.7a0-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from mplfinance) (1.1.3)
Processing c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\a6\65\5d\e2634e905fc0a7d4486dfc5acd9e68b48aae52634d82c5ed69\matplotlib-3.3.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas->mplfinance) (1.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas->mplfinance) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas->mplfinance) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3 in c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2020.06.20 in c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (2020.6.20)
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0
  Using cached Pillow-7.2.0.tar.gz (39.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->mplfinance) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas->mplfinance) (1.15.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pillow
  Building wheel for pillow (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\masanori\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-umnbxz0l\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\masanori\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-umnbxz0l\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\masanori\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-7d06m439'
       cwd: C:\Users\masanori\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-umnbxz0l\pillow\
  Complete output (172 lines):
  C:\Users\masanori\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-umnbxz0l\pillow\setup.py:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
    warnings.warn(
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  running egg_info
  writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
  writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext


  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\masanori\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-umnbxz0l\pillow\setup.py", line 864, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 290, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Users\masanori\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-umnbxz0l\pillow\setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\masanori\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-umnbxz0l\pillow\setup.py", line 918, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
  Running setup.py clean for pillow
Failed to build pillow
Installing collected packages: pillow, matplotlib, mplfinance
    Running setup.py install for pillow ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\masanori\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-umnbxz0l\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\masanori\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-umnbxz0l\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\masanori\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-f114gzuk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pillow'
         cwd: C:\Users\masanori\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-umnbxz0l\pillow\
    Complete output (174 lines):
    C:\Users\masanori\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-umnbxz0l\pillow\setup.py:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
      warnings.warn(
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\masanori\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-umnbxz0l\pillow\setup.py", line 864, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 546, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\masanori\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-umnbxz0l\pillow\setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\masanori\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-umnbxz0l\pillow\setup.py", line 918, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\masanori\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-umnbxz0l\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\masanori\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-umnbxz0l\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\masanori\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-f114gzuk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\masanori\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pillow' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: 取り敢えず、必要とされるPillowパッケージが未だPython3.9に対応していないと思われます。Python3.8環境を使うように切り替えて試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ご教示いただきありがとうございます。バージョンを下げてからインストールしたらできました。

Answer (score 1):

このエラーは、`Pillow`というパッケージのPython3.9用のWheelファイルが公式には作成・配布されていないことで発生しているようです。
[Pillow 7.2.0 Download files](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/7.2.0/#files)

Python3.9に対応する、名前に`cp39`が入っていて拡張子`.whl`の付いたファイルが無い場合、拡張子`.tar.gz`ファイルを基にビルドが行われますが、Windows環境ではそのために必要なプログラム(`zlib`?)が無くてエラーになるようです。

これはその時々の最新Pythonではよくあることのようで、昔の版数とかPillow以外Windows以外でもこんな記事があります。
[Can't install Pillow for Python 3.x in Windows - Zlib is required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38733647/9014308)
[setuptoolsインストール中のzlibエラー](http://leetmikeal.hatenablog.com/entry/20130408/1365381231)

---

対策としては以下2つのいずれかになるでしょう。

- 出来立てでこのような問題が他のパッケージでも良く起こりそうなPython 3.9環境は止めて、Python3.8環境を構築して作業を行う
- 非公式なWheelを作成・公開している[Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages - Pillow](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow) からPillowのPython3.9用のWheelをダウンロード・インストールしてからmplfinanceをインストールする

---

**追記：**
ちなみに昨日深夜(日本時間では15日早朝)に`Pillow`の版数が`8.0.0`に更新されてPython3.9用のWheelファイルもアップロードされていました。
なので、今では特に注意や対策は不要でインストール出来るでしょう。

[Pillow 8.0.0 Download files](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/8.0.0/#files)

少し待てば解決した感じですが、まあそれはPillowの開発状況を追跡している人でないと分からないタイミングでしたね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいたようにバージョンを下げてからインストールしたらできました。重ねてお礼申し上げます。